# replace multiple urls in string for different values

Tags: php, string

I've a text string with  multiple href attributes. I want to replace them with differnt links.

I've "explode" array of original links and array of links with urls that I want to replace. But I face with problem, that I dunno how to update a string with new values.

So, in a simple way

```
$sting1 = 'bla bla bla <a href="some_url">some text</a> bla bla bla <a href="some_url2">some text 2</a> bla bla bla <a href="some_url3">some text 3 3</a>';
```

and have string

```
$sting_new = 'bla bla bla <a href="some_new_url">some text</a> bla bla bla <a href="some_new_url2">some text 2</a> bla bla bla <a href="some_new_url3">some text 3 3</a>';
```

I know I can "explode" this href's and replace them, but how I can update text for $sting1?

Comment: I think you should provide an actual example, showing input and expected output. Also, if you already have any code regarding this, you might want so share that as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 approaches you can use. One is using [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php), which simply takes an array of substrings (or just single substring) to replace and an array (or single string) to replace them with.

Another approach is similar, using [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), which is similar to `str_replace`, except it uses regular expressions

Comment: `str_replace` with arrays seems to better answer the OP's question as the OP seems to have different URL values each time.

Comment: @JulienLachal you are probably right! However I feel like there's no harm in showing what other options are available :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to use a regular expression

```
<?php
$regex        = '/href="([^"]*)"/si';
$ori_string   = 'yourStringWithSomeHrefs';
$replacements = [
    'http://foo.bar',
    'relativeLink',
    // and so on
];

if(preg_match_all($regex, $ori_string, $m, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
    foreach($m[1] as $key => $value) {
        $ori_string = substr_replace($ori_string, $replacements[$key], $value[1], str_len($value[0]));
    }
}
```

Pay attention of two things

1. this code has not been tested
2. this regular expression will only be useful for double quotes href. If you need to get single and double quotes, you'll need to use a more complex regex

Comment: The `s` pattern modifier serves no purpose in this answer.